# cannot Deploy Deployment Error for module Application name is already in use. Please pick a different name.

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have Glassfish 3 server integrated with Eclipse Helios, when I try to clean project or try to republish project I am getting the following error

```
cannot Deploy Deployment Error for module  Application name  is already in use. 
Please pick a different name.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) Look for an option to force redeploy via Eclipse.

b) Try this:

1. Clean
2. Go to /domains/[yourdomain]/applications and delete the folder of your application
3. Go to /domains/[yourdomain]/config/domain.xml and search for refs to your application, e.g. any line which contains stuff like `<application-ref ref="yourApplication"` should be deleted
4. Restart Glassfish